# Swift UISearchController active time in UITableview scroll making crash

Tags: ios, swift

In my scenario, I am having `UISearchController` with `UITableview`. Here, NavigationBar Button click to showing UISearchController. UISearchController without entering text and its active time if I try to scroll tableview then I am getting `Fatal error: Index out of range`. How to solve this?

**My Code**

```
@IBAction func Click_search(_ sender: Any) {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.asciiCapable
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor =  .red
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor =  .red
        let cancelButtonAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes , for: .normal)
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return isFiltering ? filteredSections.count : sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let currentSection = isFiltering ? filteredSections[section] : sections[section]
        return currentSection.result.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return isFiltering ? filteredSections[section].title : sections[section].title
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:HomeCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! HomeCustomCell
        let section = isFiltering ? filteredSections[indexPath.section] : sections[indexPath.section]  // Here, I am getting Index out of range crash while scroll without search text enter but search active time
        let item = section.result[indexPath.row]

        return cell
}
```

Comment: cant reproduce post a github link for help

Comment: @Sh_Khan May I know how to handle this crash instead of app exit.